# This iPhone 6 is running iOS 10.1 (14B55c), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios10, xcode8

I'm trying to run the app after I updated Xcode to v8 and iOS to v10, but this error message pops up & prevents me from doing so:

> This iPhone 6 is running iOS 10.1 (14B55c), which may not be supported
>   by this version of Xcode.

[image]
What should I do to get rid of this?

Comment: For iOS 11.0 and above use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383054/2866371)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To use the iOS 10.1 beta you need to use the Xcode 8.1 beta. Xcode 8 doesn't support the iOS 10.1 beta.

And now since iOS 10.1 and Xcode 8.1 are out of beta, be sure you update to the latest, non-beta of both.

Comment: Oh sweet, another 4GB "minor release." ;)

Comment: Unfortunately with iOS 10.1 released, current Xcode does still not support that.

Comment: No matter how I look in the App store, Xcode 8.1 is not released. Downloading the GM seed of Xcode 8.1 now. Normally they release these things simultaneously.

Answer (score 25):

**Update** Xcode 8.1 is now available on the app store, so you should just update your Xcode to the latest: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

---

It looks like iOS 10.1 was released today, but not Xcode 8.1. If you upgraded your devices to 10.1, you'll need to download the Xcode 8.1 GM Seed in order to deploy to your devices running iOS 10.1.

You can download the 8.1 GM Seed here: https://developer.apple.com/download/

GM Seed's are typically the final version that gets released to the app store.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my iOS to 10.1 and was going crazy why it was happening and I was refreshing app store constantly to check whether they have released Xcode 8.1 or not.

Answer (score 5):

The public Xcode 8 release does not support iOS 10.1 beta. Apple released beta builds of macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and iOS 10.1 a few days ago. But watchOS, tvOS and Xcode are not included in Apple's public betas.

Comment: Which “beta”? — iOS 10.1 has been released.

Answer (score 4):

You need Xcode 8.1 GM to use your 10.1 device. BUT it's really absurd to release a new iOS version without releasing the respective Xcode version. Something really weird.

Answer (score 1):

- First: [ios sdk download here 10.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dng3iBph4TYY9V4BxPPYtLsY35XsNJX7)
- Second: Copy files to: Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
- Third: Restart your Xcode