# Use Xcode 8 with iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11

I want to use Xcode 8 with iOS 11.

should I upgrade my Xcode. However, my code can't be built by the new compiler, so I want to stay with Xcode 8.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

**Apple revealed several new iOS 11 features at WWDC 2017.**

Comment: @holex Why down voted me could you tell me please  .  i want xcode 8 for iOS 11

Comment: Just so you know, that setting means: whats the minimum OS version. You are saying: this app runs on 10.1 and higher. (At this same time, you really should use Xcode 9 for the iOS11 simulator)

Comment: Can someone please upload his DeviceSupport folder for iOS 11 on Google drive and share the link?

Comment: not run iOS 11 simulator Xcode 8.2.1 any idea without Xcode 9.2 install  run iOS 11 simulator working...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Check this out: **As of now this is only for Debugging on iOS device not Simulator**

1. Download the SDK [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/download/)
2. Copy this **iOS 11.0 image** file to: **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/**
3. Restart Xcode.

Comment: I don't think it's a great idea to host this image file. The file is freely available to download via xCode11. In addition, this image can and will update regularly.

Comment: The second link looks like a phishing website :/

Comment: 2nd link is redirecting to fake fb page, not work bro

Comment: Sorry guys. I just update the link. Thanks for your feedbacks.

Comment: any idea without install Xcode 9 beta run iOS device  .... any one this solution find ask me ...

Comment: Copied iOS 11.1 folder from Xcode 9.1 Package Contents,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1443wlYRC4JwGEhe9bd0mefocAY9Zx2s2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I also want 11.2 @mramosch did you got it ?

Comment: @AshishKarpe you can go to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928402/4935811

Comment: @AshishKarpe - Rajan was so kind to upload it for us! You can find it here in the accepted answer:stackoverflow.com/questions/39864771/…

Comment: Can anyone share the 11.2.5?

Comment: @SourLeangChhean did you have ios 12 simulator ?

Comment: @SourLeangChhean can you upload it into your drive (google , Dropbox) and share it with me and other developers ?

Comment: You can download the older versions of XCode here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 63):

**As of now this is only for Debugging on iOS device, not Simulator**

Xcode 8 could not support unless you have the DeviceSupport folder for the iOS 11 version.

1. You can download a Xcode 9 beta (latest Xcode 9) or get an DeviceSupport folder from other user.
2. Simply copy it to your folder or create an symbolic link

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0\ \(15A372\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0`

reference: [Use Xcode 7 with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/use-xcode-7-with-ios-10)

Comment: Note that this will only allow you to debug your code running on an iOS 11 device in Xcode 8. It will not allow Xcode 8's iOS Simulator to run iOS 11. So you'll need to have a physical device running iOS 11 for this.

Comment: Thanks! Nice trick. This worked for me. The command line tools selection of the other answer didn't work.

Comment: It seems not be working with Xcode 9 beta 6 and iOS 11 (15A5361a) :/

Comment: make sure you copy the correct folder which has DeveloperDiskImage.dmg file

Comment: I had to use it with https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484076/849616 to make everything work with Xcode 9.4 and Xcode 8.3.3.

Answer (score 7):

I did this and it's fine, I still work both on comercial app using Xcode 8 + Swift 3 and exploring Xcode 9 beta with Swift 4. Just download the Xcode 9 and, inside Xcode 8 preferences, set the Command Line Tools to use the 9.0.

[image: Xcode Preferences > Locations]

Comment: Tried that on beta 6 and it just didn't work for me, I got the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I preferred to copy ALL the folder:

```
/Volumes/**HighSierra**/Applications/Xcode-**beta.app**/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0\ \(15A5278f\)
```

to:

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/**11**
```

I can confirm I can run on my iPhone 7 with iOS 11

Comment: This also works with Xcode 9.1(iOS 11.1). Just restart Xcode 8.3.3 after copying files.