# Is there any way of obtaining Developer Disk Image of iOS 11 for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, ios11, xcode9-beta

Currently I'm using macOS Sierra with Xcode 8 installed. I just updated my device to iOS 11, which is my main development device. I can't build the apps I'm working on anymore because Xcode 8 has no iOS 11 Development Disk Image. Is there any way of obtaining the image (without installing Xcode 9) or I'll have to go back to iOS 10 in order to build to my device?

Comment: Xcode 9 exists for Sierra.  (Apple says: "Xcode 9.0 requires a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later.")

Comment: Oh, I think you're right. I've tried to install it on a way older Macbook. It seems that it is not running on Sierra. Sorry. Still, is there any way of obtaining the just the developer disk image from somewhere?

Comment: Apple doesn't support that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Xcode 8 with iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381860/use-xcode-8-with-ios-11)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928402/4935811 or Use Xcode 8 with iOS 11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426754/4935811

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426754/4935811

Comment: @RobertSandru, You can download the disk image from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0SKYq_SEPH8TG51dzliV2lINFU?usp=sharing

Comment: @RobertSandru This developer disk image is also working in Xcode 7.3.2 for iOS 11.0.2 (Even i'm running EL Capitan) Thanks man!

Comment: @AKNinan Can you pls upload developer disk image for 11.3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download All Older and latest Disk Image Platform version [Here](https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases)

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383054/4146322

On another note, it is nearly impossible to revert to iOS 10 once you install iOS 11. Apple has incorporated checks for this at a deep level to prevent people installing older and possibly unsecured versions. You can read up on this at Apple's [iOS10 Security Documentation](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) in the second paragraph of page 6.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get your Xcode 8, work with iOS 11.

1. [Download](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_4/Xcode_9_beta_4.xip) Xcode 9 Image File with iOS 11 beta
2. Copy iOS 11.0 Image File to following location in your system: `~/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`

**or**

2. Create Symbolic Link Using: 

   `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0\ \(15A5278f\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0`
3. Restart Xcode.

Answer (score -4):

Download developer disk image from [Here.](http://festyy.com/wcycWR)
and copy that two folders to below mentioned path.

First open spotlight search and go to your `xcode` and from right click ->
Show package content Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport

Skip ads from above link and then you can download