# Using iOS8 and later devices with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, ios11, ios12

Using iOS8 and later devices with Xcode?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426754/4935811

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Xcode 8 with iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381860/use-xcode-8-with-ios-11)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Up to iOS 12.1 is available

You can download DeveloperDiskImage.dmg [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7toqnozcxr8mfu4/AAAeEwZikMlCu3CiCDf9AyeCa?dl=0) or [here](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

Steps:

1.Download Zip file and extract.

2.Click on "Finder" in MAC OS

3.Click on "Go to Folder"

4.Paste /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport . Otherwise go to Applications > Right Click on Xcode > Show Package Contents and follow the directories above.

5.Reboot Device + Xcode + Mac

Comment: #5 is important, trying to solve this for like half an hour until I restart my Mac

Answer (score 16):

Well you have two options:

1)Straightforward, download [Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/5090735) and you are good to go.

2) You need to put `DeveloperDiskImage` of iOS 11 in

/Applications/Xcode8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Put iOS 11 DiskImage [image: here]

and you can find this diskImage in Xcode9 at same path in case you want to continue with XCode8

Path of iOS 11 Disk Image:

> ~/Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0

```
NOTE: Xcode 9.0 requires a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later.
```

Comment: do you know where I can download DeveloperDiskImage for iOS 11?

Comment: actually when u install Xcode 9, it will be there on your /Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/DeviceSupport. You can copy it from there.

Comment: thanks, actually I've done that right after asking you about it lol. just went to developer center and  downloaded Xcode 9 and extract the files.

Comment: @CodeOverRide You can download the Disk Image from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0SKYq_SEPH8TG51dzliV2lINFU?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why software no longer installs, such as you can't install Sierra or Xcode 9 has more to do with Apple making your computer obsolete.

Here is a recent ([2016 Addition to machines no longer supported by Apple](https://www.macrumors.com/2016/11/29/early-2009-to-early-2011-macs-obsolete/)), and there are so surprises there.

I have a perfectly running iMac Early  2008, and 2 years ago it was placed on the obsolete list. I can no longer update certain programs, such as install Sierra or Xcode 9.2.

There are some very disgruntled people who purchased MacBooks and Apple made them obsolete without even introducing an upgraded machine to replace it.

Now, if I want to have my Apps run on the new iOS 11 OS, I need to replace a perfectly good and working machine. That is not right.

Answer (score -1):

You can't run ios 11 on Xcode 8.2

You need Xcode 9 beta

https://developer.apple.com/download/

> Xcode 9 beta requires a Mac running macOS 10.12.4 or later. Xcode 9
>   beta includes SDKs for iOS 11, watchOS 4, macOS 10.13, and tvOS 11

.