# ios 11 Beta 5 select drop-down list issue

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, ios11

HTML Select drop-down list is not getting dismissed properly on iOS 11 beta 5. Upon closing the drop-down, an empty drop-down with blank options reappears in its place.

Please let me know if anyone else experienced the same issue and if a workaround is available for the same.

Note: It is a hybrid app built for iPad only and this issue is not reproducible on iOS 10 or below.

Comment: It's a beta for a reason. Apple speaks against developing for their beta platforms. Wait until they release the documentation on iOS 11 prior to starting development.

Comment: File a bug report for this issue at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @Brxxn Develop *FOR*? Probably not. No-one should develop for a apple's betas. Develop *WITH*? If you need it, it wouldn't be a stupid idea. The betas are there for developers that want to build apps that take advantage of the new iOS features, and it shouldn't be discouraged to develop with it. It gives them a nice headstart and ensures that the new features will be taken advantage of at launch. Plus, it helps apple wiggle out all the bugs.

Comment: I have the same issue happens on ios 11 final version.

Comment: Having same issue in latest iOS 11 release version.

Comment: I have the same issue in iOS 11.0.2

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941124/html-select-drop-down-issue-with-cordova-on-ios-11-beta) and see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941124/html-select-drop-down-issue-with-cordova-on-ios-11-beta

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and discovered that in the `<option>` tag there is a `label=""` value. This only affects iOS 11, and 10 we've noticed as well. Populate your `label=""` value.

Comment: This fixed our issue. We're using Twitter Bootstrap and Angular. Inside of a modal we had a long select dropdown list. When the dropdown was activated, it kept shifting our DOM elements and then touch points got messed up. Using this solution worked!

Comment: Adding a label to the options did not fix this for me.

Comment: This did not fix for me

Answer (score 0):

[solution in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403989/3266024)

This is not a long-term solution, but it works until apple provides a fix.

**main points of other answer**

Build your app with xcode 8, you can download version 8 of xcode from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download), you have to sign in using your apple id.

To be able to build to iOS11 you will have to download xcode 9 (unless you have it) as well, and then copy the `11.0` folder from `xCode9/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` and paste it into the same place in xCode8

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because Cordova is using a UIWebView, and the bug is with UIWebView in iOS 11. The issue has been fixed in xcode 9.2-beta. Tested and it is working fine in iOS 11.2. Hopefully xcode 9.2 will have the fix once released.