# html-select drop down issue with cordova on IOS 11 Beta

Tags: cordova, select, drop-down-menu, html-select, ios11

I currently build an IOS application using AngularJS and Cordova. I find a bug when I tried my app on IOS 11 Beta.

To select some data in a form, we use select dropDown. When we select a value, the drop down list disappears but it appear again some seconds after.

When I have multiple select on my form, when a tap on a second select the first is selected. Then after selected the value the good list of option appear.

I try with basic sample and this is the same behaviour. In a web explorer or with IOS 10, there is no bug.

```
  <select ng-model="elements" ng-options="serie.nom for serie in elements"></select>
```

I try to add label, Update Cordova and IOS plugins. But nothing works.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Having the same problem, but it seems to be an issue with UIWebView. If loading a page with select in a regular (not Cordova) app in a UIWebView, it has the same problem.

Comment: Any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had reported this issue for Cordova below:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13287

It appears the bug in Apple's `UIWebView` that cordova uses for IOS. I worked with one of our IOS developers to create a sample native IOS app using just `Swift` (no `Cordova`). The issue with the dropdown was present there too.

Apple seems to have another view called `WKWebView`, which seems to be preferred one starting from IOS 8.0. Below is the quote taken from Apple's [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) documentation. I have verified there is no issue with the dropdown under WKWebView.

> **Important**
>
> Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content
>   to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

Good thing is Cordova has support for `WKWebView` too. You have to install the plugin: [`cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine)

The plugin is not foolproof yet. You can try if that plugin works for your entire application. As of yet, WKWebView is not the default view that Cordova uses. Hopefully, Cordova will make WKWebView as default view soon. They are tracking all the known issues with WKWebView [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12074?jql=labels%20%3D%20wkwebview-known-issues).

**Update: Nov 3, 2017**

I had reported this issue to apple too. But unfortunately, it was flagged as a duplicate of some other issue reported to them. For security and privacy reasons, apple didn't provide me the details about the other issue. The status of that issue is CLOSED now (it was OPEN before). So, hopefully the fix will be shipped into the upcoming IOS updates.

**Update: Feb 1, 2018**

I just noticed that Apple has fixed this issue for `UIWebView` too under `Xcode 9.2`.

Comment: this plugin is not supporting in my project. Any other solution please...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very useful.

Comment: In our app we were already using wkwebview and the problem was present. It seems to be worse using a device with ios 11

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because Cordova is using a UIWebView, and the bug is with UIWebView in iOS 11. The issue has been fixed in iOS 11.2 SDK. Xcode 9.2 having iOS 11.2 SDK seems to have resolved this issue.