# ionic - Drop down list flickers in iPAD

Tags: ios, ipad, ionic-framework, drop-down-menu, flicker

Dropdown list in my Ionic application flickers in iPAD.

[1. On Dropdown Tap]

[image]

[2. If Tap on outside dropdown list]

[image]

[3. If Tap inside dropdown list]
Once again the Image 1 will be shown.

It worked fine with iPhone 5s. But not in iPAD.

Any solution or workaround ?

**EDIT:**

Even if I change the orientation of iPAD, it shows the previously listed dropdown contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with recent update of iOS 11 and Apple's UIWebView. It works well with Apple's WKWebView.

Resolved the issue by installing cordova's WKWebView.

```
>> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine --save
```

Then adding the following in config.xml:

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Reference links:

1. [WKWebView Engine plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine)
2. [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)
3. [Cordova forum](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13287)
4. [Other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941124/html-select-drop-down-issue-with-cordova-on-ios-11-beta)

Comment: you save my day thanks. The only problem is that if you use worker you can have browser sercurity error. And you just have to handle it

Comment: Glad, it helped you :) Even though the solution worked, Just go through the reference link for better understanding and new changes in their plugin.