# Ionic worker's creation on wkwebview on ios 11: SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure

Tags: ios, ipad, ionic-framework, web-worker

I am facing ***SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure***. There are a lot of issues related "***to dom security exception***" but none fit my need.

First,
I had a drop down list problem in IOS 11.0.3 thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365944/ionic-drop-down-list-flickers-in-ipad/46590038?noredirect=1#comment85904617_46590038). I found a way to resolved it.

But now when I am trying to create a worker i have a SecurityError (DOM Exception 18).
The exception occured when i did :

```
var pdfWorkerBlob = new Worker('scripts/pdfmake-worker-blob.js');
```

By the way it is a worker we use for printing pdf with the pdfmakejs.  This line worked fine before I use the **cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine** I am using ionic. The result of the following command is:

```
ionic info 
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.8
    @ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.20.0

System:

    Node : v8.7.0
    npm  : 5.7.1
    OS   : macOS High Sierra
```

Here is a screenshot of the exception

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a way to resolve my problem.

In the case you are facing this problem not in ionic. 
The best approach seems that you have to deploy a light **local webserver** to serve
your scripts.

[**Caddy**](https://github.com/mholt/caddy) can be a good tool for that. 
Thanks to the @Matt(Matt Holt) by the way. This solution was suggested by him in a [topic on **github**](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/269) and it inpires me for my solution.

Having said that, as we are using **ionic**. We already have a local web server that can serve the script.

First I get the application url with:

```
var rootUrl=document.URL.split('#')[0];
```

And then i can create my worker like this :

```
pdfmakeWorkerBlob = new Worker(rootUrl+'scripts/pdfmake-worker-blob.js');
```

And no more dom exception security problem.

For those who are not familiar witth web workers this [page](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-enviornment-loadingscripts) is a great start