# iOS 11 UIWebView drop down menus completely broken on iPad - UIPopoverController

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, dropdown, uipopovercontroller, ios11

When using HTML select element, `UIWebView` presents a native `UIPopoverController` as dropdown list on iPad (iPhone uses `UIPickerView` which works fine).

On iOS11 this appears to be completely broken:

- Clicking outside dropdown to dismiss without selecting an option results in popover being closed and immediately re-presented, occasionally empty
- When more than one drop down on the page, drop down for new list contains elements from previous list
- When selecting second drop down, first one re-opens
- Occassionally drop down appears in top left corner (presumably lost it's source view)
- Above steps very occasionally result in the following crash:

> 2017-09-23 09:43:13.190728+0100 Web[1779:86622] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UITableView dataSource is not set'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4a01cb **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010c8bbf41 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010d4a5362 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98    3
>
>   Foundation                          0x000000010c360089
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193     4
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010da742f5 -[UITableView
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1756    5   UIKit                               0x000000010da7451a -[UITableView
>   _createPreparedCellForRowAtIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 81   6   UIKit                               0x000000010da82137 -[UITableView _heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 208   7
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010dd2b939
>   -[UISectionRowData heightForRow:inSection:canGuess:] + 259    8   UIKit                               0x000000010dd31c1a -[UITableViewRowData
>   heightForRow:inSection:canGuess:adjustForReorderedRow:] + 277     9
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010dd36230
>   -[UITableViewRowData ensureHeightsFaultedInForScrollToIndexPath:withScrollPosition:boundsHeight:]
>   + 964     10  UIKit                               0x000000010da51110 -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]
>   + 2783    11  UIKit                               0x000000010da51b8f -[UITableView _scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:usingPresentationValues:]
>   + 146     12  UIKit                               0x000000010da51a11 -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 123   13  UIKit                               0x000000010de72d11
>   -[UIWebSelectTableViewController viewWillAppear:] + 247   14  UIKit                               0x000000010dabe9b0 -[UIViewController
>   _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 444   15  UIKit                               0x000000010dabf245 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 147  16 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010da8b881
>   __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 1088  17  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010d926c61 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318  18  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010d91530d _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 280     19 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010d945600
>   _afterCACommitHandler + 137   20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d442db7
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d442d0e
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430  22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d427324 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572    23  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010d426a89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409     24  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001124c89c6 GSEventRunModal + 62   25  UIKit
>   0x000000010d91ad30 UIApplicationMain + 159    26  Web
>   0x000000010bfb014f main + 111     27  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000110df1d81 start + 1  28  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1`

I created a sample application with one line of code which demonstrates the issue:

https://github.com/AshRobinson/BrokenUIWebView

http://gph.is/2xmHFWs

Does anyone have a workaround for such issue? Migrating to `WKWebview` is not an option for us at this stage.

Is there any way to force iPad to use `UIPickerView` for dropdowns as per iPhone temporarily?

I have investigated suggestions in other stack overflow posts with no luck, for example:

[ios 11 Beta 5 select drop-down list issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619087/ios-11-beta-5-select-drop-down-list-issue)

Comment: Having the same problem. No solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same bug. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) says that any app iOS 8+ should be using WKWebView. Once we switched to WKWebView, we are no longer seeing this issue.

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue even with WKWebView upgrade

Comment: @dmorrow Here is my very simple [gist](https://gist.github.com/egrudolph/842df35faa7cc10b054b1b5b6e920f5f)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, with a WKWebView that was being added into an UIWindow directly. My problem was that the view didn't have an UIViewcontroller linked to it, so the following lines did the trick:

```
containerVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[containerVC.view addSubview:myWkWebview];
[window addSubview:containerVC.view];
```

Instead of adding `myWkWebview` directly to the window. With this, modal views were added again :-)