# Is it possible to compile and test Ios 12 beta without xcode 10 beta?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to compile with iOS 12 and test in the simulator but i don't want install Xcode 10 Beta.

Is that possible?

Best regards
Tino

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884571/is-it-possible-to-compile-latest-swift-version-on-older-xcode) could be related.

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Because of the latest version of Xcode (9.4.1) only supports devices up to 11.4.1. For testing in iOS 12 beta, you **must** install Xcode 10 beta.

Xcode 10 beta can coexist with previous version of Xcode, so don't worry about installing and using it.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I didn't know that both version Can be installed in parallel.