# iPhone 7 with iOS 11 not working on xcode8.3.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
  This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 11.0 (15A372), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.
```

My iPhone stopped working with xcode when I update my device to iOS 11. I don't want to update my Xcode as I don't want to have make any unnecessary changes to my code right now.

Please advise is there any possibility of running my app on ios 11 device without updating xcode

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381860/use-xcode-8-with-ios-11

Comment: for another ex https://medium.com/swiftist/how-to-use-ios-11-beta-installed-device-with-xcode-8-c255b916aca5

Comment: Thanks, will try now :)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik .. Thanks man..It works !!

Comment: welcome bro,...