# Please share iOS 11.1 image file

Tags: xcode

Updated my iOS to 11.1 and now my Xcode can't run the app. Need to add iOS 11.1 image file to Device Support folder to run my app. But I can't find it online. Please someone who installed 'Xcode 9.1 beta' share it with me. Here is an instruction how to get it:

It should be 11.1 folder.
[image]

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because it is not programming-related.

Comment: Just download Xcode 9.1 beta and install it next to 9.0 and your done.

Comment: @rckoenes my internet connection is low, but I need it ASAP for presentation, so if you have beta I would be thankful if you share it.

Comment: That would be illegal, can't do that.

Comment: @rckoens are you serious? couldn't see it in user agreements. I found here the post but it is for 11.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381860/use-xcode-8-with-ios-11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repository holds the device support files for the iOS, and it updates regularly. 
https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Comment: Please don't leave link only answers. This link can break at any time. If you must, leave as a comment on the original question - you only need 50 repo to do that.

Comment: @AshleyMills the user was asking for the ios11.1 image file and I posted it as an answer.
I don't know what is the problem

Comment: The problem is… _"links can break at any time"_, leaving your answer invalid.

Comment: Please provide the disk image  iOS 11.1.2 (15B202) also.

Comment: Does you have 11.2 developer disk ?