# How to use iOS 11.1 device with Xcode 8 or earlier?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8

I want to install my app on iOS 11 device using xcode8. I don't wan't to update xcode.

Comment: you can't. you need Xcode9.

Comment: if we can run an app on iOS 10 device using xcode7 than why not this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Xcode 8 with iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381860/use-xcode-8-with-ios-11)

Answer (score 2):

Just found device support files for iOS 11.1 and 11.2 (15C5097c) devices. Copy these files to DeviceSupport Folder using following method:

Open Finder window -> Select **GO** from Finder Menu -> Select **Go to folder** and paste following path...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

you can find **11.1** device support file from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vZHgF0-8yqet2581oioupGz-J6l4Lp97

and **11.2** from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jfj2nqWK0Aktvnrd5wlMK-zBVaXjDml5

Answer (score 0):

You can update it to test flight. Once you did that, you can download it on your iOS 11 device. Of course you need an official development account from Apple.(Paying the 99 euros). But that's the only way.